# Наследование форм Django

Tags: django, наследование, формы

Вопрос достаточно простой и, скорее канонический, однако решение не работает.
В Django 2.2 проекте необходимо реализовать 2 разные модельные HTML-формы, имеющие общие поля. Общие поля заданы классом формы `EntryForm`, от которого наследуются формы `Form1` и `Form2`. Базовый класс с общими полями используется только для наследования.

Прописываем таким образом:

**forms.py**

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:    
        model = Entry 
        fields = ['name', 'dateReg']                  
        widgets = {'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-horizontal', }),
                   'dateReg': forms.DateInput(format=('%d.%m.%Y'), }),
        }
```

**Пробовал так:**

```
class Form1(EntryForm):
    class Meta(EntryForm.Meta): 
        fields = ['jobtype', 'position']                  
        widgets = {'jobtype': forms.Select(),
                   'position': forms.Select(),
                }
```

**И так пробовал:**

```
class Form2(EntryForm):
   class Meta(EntryForm.Meta): 
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields = EntryForm.Meta.fields + ['castomer', 'product']                  
            self.widgets = EntryForm.Meta.widgets.update({'castomer': forms.Select(),
                                                          'product': forms.Select()
                                                        })
```

Как мы видим, обе формы унаследованы, также унаследован класс `Meta` с добавлением разных полей. После инициализации экземпляр `newForm1` содержит переопределенный набор полей, а `newForm2`: содержит только поля базовой формы.

```
newForm1 = Form1() # fields: ['jobtype', 'position']
newForm2 = Form2() # fields: ['name', 'dateReg']
```

> Что необходимо изменить чтобы наследники базовой формы имели её
>   поля и свои собственные, и соответственно, их виджеты?

Comment: Попробуйте `fields = EntryForm.Meta.fields + ['jobtype', 'position']`

Comment: и `init` пишится на уровне с `Meta`

Comment: Попробуйте, как тут https://chriskief.com/2013/06/30/django-form-inheritance/